# What causes a Kendo UI scheduler to refresh the events displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, kendo-ui, scheduler

I have a webpage with a KendoUI Scheduler (I am using Chrome and have the developer console open). The resources appear on the right side correctly, but there are no events on the board. As soon as I resize the Chrome developer console (drag up or down a little bit) the events appear on the scheduler.

I've tried to find what event or call is being made when I resize the developer console so that I can always call it by default so that the events appear by default but have been unable to find anything useful.

What event or function is being called when I resize the developer console that causes the scheduler to refresh it's self?

Neither of these worked:

```
var timeLineView = $("#TimeLineView");
timeLineView.dataSource.fetch();
timeLineView.refresh();
```

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani I added the code

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue in https://dojo.telerik.com/UWaqI but no avail

Comment: @JayeshGoyani That example shows no resources on the right nor the event that in the data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timeLineView.dataSource.read();
timeLineView.refresh();
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why this solves your problem?